# How to narrow down a generic type based on object property type

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

I want to create a Typescript utility type `ExtractOnProp` that extracts an object from a union type `T` whose specific property `Prop` has a requested type `ValueType`.

```js
type ExtractOnProp<T, Prop extends keyof T, ValueType> = /* ... */;

type Test1 = ExtractOnProp<
  | { value: "test1" | "test2", prop1: any }
  | { value: "test1", prop2: any }
  | { value: "test3", prop3: any },
  "value",
  "test1">;
// Test1 == { value: "test1", prop1: any } | { value: "test1", prop2: any };

// Real use case is more complicated but example usage:
// We want to find an element from an array of possible values
function narrow<
  T extends { value: string },
  Value extends readonly T['value'][],
>(
  elements: readonly T[],
  filter: Value,
): ExtractOnProp<T, 'value', Value[number]> {
  const result = elements.find((el) => filter.includes(el.value as any));
  if (!result) {
    throw new Error('not found');
  }
  return result as any;
}
narrow(
  [
    { value: 'test1', prop1: 1 },
    { value: 'test2', prop1: 2 },
    { value: 'test3', prop3: 3 },
  ] as const,
  ['test1', 'test3'] as const,
);
// { value: 'test1', prop1: 1 } | { value: 'test3', prop3: 3 }
```

Here are the things I've tried

```js
type ExtractOnProp<T, Prop extends keyof T, ValueType> = T[Prop] extends ValueType ? T : never;
// Always returns never

// The closest I got was property type intersection
type IntersectPropType<T, Prop extends keyof T, ValueType> = T[Prop] extends infer S
  ? S extends ValueProp
    ? S
    : never
  : never;
type Test1 = IntersectPropType<{ value: 'test1' | 'test2' } | { value: "test3"; prop: any }, 'value', 'test2' | 'omitted'>;
// Test1 = 'test2';
```

**Edit:**

I've gotten closer now by narrowing the union, but not the property type itself.

```js
type ExtractOnProp<T, Prop extends keyof T, ValueType> = T extends {
  [_ in Prop]: infer S;
}
  ? ValueType extends S
    ? T
    : never
  : never;

type Test = ExtractOnProp<
  { value: 'a' | 'c'; prop1: any } | { value: 'b'; prop2: any },
  'value',
  'a'
>;
// Test = { value: 'a' | 'c', prop1: any }
```

Comment: Please fix the typos in your `type Test = ...` line

Comment: Why do you expect `Test` to include `{ value: "test1", prop1: any }` when the relevant union member is `{ value: "test1" | "test2", prop1: any }`?  Is this another typo or do you actually want `ExtractOnProp` to do something more invasive than just extracting union members?

Comment: And what specific type should be output for `ExtractOnProp<{ value: 'test1' | 'test2' } | { value: "test3"; prop: any }, 'value', 'test2' | 'omitted'>`? You don't want `"test2"` coming out, but what type *should* come out?  Should it be `{value: 'test1' | 'test2'}`?  Should it be `{value: 'test2'}`?   Should it be `never`?  Please explicitly detail what you mean by "extract"

Comment: Your last edit does not, unfortunately, constitute an answer to my last two questions. Unless you answer those I can't help.  If you do decide to answer them, please let me know in a comment so I am alerted.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz
Just finished updating.
Comment 1: Fixed.

Comment 2: I've added an example `narrow` that illustrates why the property is narrowed as well.

Comment 3: For my use case unspecified. For a general case, I think an intersection should happen, narrowed T that matches some of ValueType.

I've also got a bit closer in the edit section.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKyAGN) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: By the way, what does `T extends unknown` accomplish?

Comment: I’ll explain when I write up my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your requirements as stated, one approach might be:

```
type ExtractOnProp<T, K extends keyof T, V> =
    T extends unknown ? V extends T[K] ?
    { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? T[P] & V : T[P] }
    : never : never
```

This is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in both `T` and `V`. That means the operation will *distribute* across [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T` and `V`; `T` and `V` will be split into their union members, the type will be evaluated for each such member, and then the result will be rejoined into a union.  So `ExtractOnProp<T1 | T2, K, V1 | V2>` will be the same as `ExtractOnProp<T1, K, V1> | ExtractOnProp<T2, K, V1> | ExtractOnProp<T1, K, V2> | ExtractOnProp<T2, K, V2>`.  You definitely want to do this with `T`, since part of the point is to examine each union member of `T` separately; and if you don't distribute across unions in `T`, you end up examining all of `T` at once which is not going to help.

Conditional types are only distributive this way when the checked type is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  The type `V extends T[K] ? { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? T[P] & V : T[P] } : never` would not be distributive in `T`.  In order to make it so, we can wrap it in the seemingly useless `T extends unknown ? (...) : never`.  Of course `T` will extend `unknown`; we don't really want to *check* it.  Instead we just want to split `T` into its union members before evaluating the rest of the type.

So, the rest of the type is

```
V extends T[K] ? { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? T[P] & V : T[P] } : never
```

This has the effect of splitting `V` into its union members also.  If the member of `V` is not assignable to the property at key `K` of `T`, then we want to drop this `T` member from the output (hence the `never`).  If it *is* assignable, then we want to grab this member.  But instead of just returning `T`, we [map it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to `{[P in keyof T]: P extends K ? T[P] & V : T[P] }`.  That type is basically just `T` except for the property at `K`, which gets [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `V`.  This way if the property is wider than `V` it will be narrowed.

---

Let's test it out:

```
type Test = ExtractOnProp<
    { value: "test1" | "test2", prop1: any } |
    { value: "test1", prop2: any } |
    { value: "test3", prop3: any },
    "value", "test1">
// type Test = 
//   { value: "test1";  prop1: any; } | 
//   { value: "test1";  prop2: any; }
```

Looks good, the `"test3"` member is dropped entirely, while the `"test1" | "test2"` member is narrowed a bit.

Next test:

```
const ret = narrow([
    { value: 'test1', prop1: 1 },
    { value: 'test2', prop1: 2 },
    { value: 'test3', prop3: 3 },
] as const, ['test1', 'test3'] as const);
/* const ret: {
    readonly value: "test1";
    readonly prop1: 1;
    readonly prop3?: undefined;
} | {
    readonly value: "test3";
    readonly prop3: 3;
    readonly prop1?: undefined;
} */
```

Again, seems reasonable.  More:

```
type Test1 = ExtractOnProp<
    { value: 'test1' | 'test2' } |
    { value: "test3"; prop: any },
    'value', 'test2' | 'omitted'>;
// type Test1 = {  value: "test2"; }
```

Fine, I think?  Last one:

```
type Test2 = ExtractOnProp<
    { value: 'a' | 'c'; prop1: any } |
    { value: 'b'; prop2: any },
    'value',
    'a'
>;
// type Test2 = { value: "a"; prop1: any;}
```

Okay, those all do what I think you want.  These sorts of type manipulations always seem to have a lot of edge cases, so I'd be surprised if there isn't *some* feature that behaves differently from how you want.  So test thoroughly and hopefully if something isn't the way you want it you can modify this yourself.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-CBlR-ZsMTbS9rG-Z1FnRG5tB8ZRqU9ZIGEvbFbEA4DoPxCdETuCCZCgl1YJ8G4COkIiYOmbp4KgRCIGQiBUMkZZH0BSlgS7eE6wbacWx8dt0PHLY9wPfYnlIikJDycBwSJUoQwqcNqmIVZhJ4okNQGSc+y07E1JwhFbhRUCXgXGQY02Xcdn7bSNXwK0nGAAwGA1TNcTBQoelKOxDMJYpxixSlPIhAKFPKMMqkjAzuw1ZAtMGDVUA1VFBzM-TZXUnsUxS0DDiPY43lWSzWjjYr4skdyJE4kK+x8vyhmQEy0oKkBkViIA)

Comment: This seems like dark magic, but I've been trying to write a function to narrow a union of object types based on one or more possible values for a particular key and this is *exactly* what I've been looking for. Thanks!